# How to use DateFNS in CodePen? (dateFns is not defined)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, codepen, date-fns

I need to use the [DateFNS](https://date-fns.org/) in a CodePen but can't get it to work.
Error:

> "[Vue warn]: Error in data(): 'ReferenceError: dateFns is not defined'
>   (found in < Root>)"

Here is my example CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKqxmd

```
    <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title primary-title>
            <div>
              <h3 class="headline mb-0">DATE {{ todaysDateMin }}</h3>
            </div>
          </v-card-title>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>

    import { format } from 'date-fns'
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {    
      todaysDateMin: dateFns.format(new Date(), '[Today is a] dddd')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: First, add the dateFns script. Then remove your import. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/YvmBrR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CodePen go to `Settings -> JavaScript` and in the **External Resource search** type `date-fns` and select from the dropdown list.

Then to call it you need to append `dateFns.`, just like you are already doing.

```
dateFns.format(new Date(), '[Today is a] dddd')
```

And remove the import statement

Comment: Thank you. How to add internationalization to it? https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/I18n `  data () {
    return { esLocale: 'date-fns/locale/es', todaysDateMin: dateFns.format(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD', {locale:  dateFns.esLocale}),`

Comment: @Tom It is not supported via CDN, non-CommonJS packages. See https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/I18n#usage

Comment: @Tom I would suggest to use CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/ if you want to create VueJS apps. You have the full power of NPM and can install libraries as if it were in your local dev machine. There you can use internationalization and supports ES Modules

Comment: how come `date.formatRelative` is undefined?

Answer (score 2):

You're doing `import { format } from 'date-fns'` so you just need to do `format(new Date(), '[Today is a] dddd')` and not `dateFns.format` because like the rror says, dateFns is not defined